# Jacoco Report Merging

Tags: java, jacoco

I am using Jacoco on a remote websphere server. I have it set up as a tcpsrver and I query the server to get the `jacoco.exec`, using this file I can create reports for all my projects. What I want is a single report for all the projects. I have added each report to a list, but when I try to create a single report, I am only able to view the statistics for the last project.

Each project is in its own folder, each folder gets its own `coveragereport`. I do it like this

```
File[] fList = directory.listFiles();

        ReportGenerator rg = new  ReportGenerator();

        for(File file : fList)
        {
            if( file.getAbsolutePath().contains("BL") )
            {
                if( new File( file.getAbsolutePath() + "\\bin" ).isDirectory() )
                {
                    rg = new  ReportGenerator(file);
                    rg.setExecutionDataFile(directory);
                    rg.setClassesDirectory(file, "\\bin");
                    rg.setReportDirectory(directory);
                    rg.setTitle(file);
                    rg.create();
                }       
            }
            else
            {
                if( new File( file.getAbsolutePath() + "\\WebContent" ).isDirectory() )
                {
                    rg = new  ReportGenerator(file);
                    rg.setExecutionDataFile( directory );
                    rg.setClassesDirectory( file , "\\WebContent\\WEB-INF\\classes" );
                    rg.setReportDirectory(directory);
                    rg.setTitle(file);
                    rg.create();
                }
            }
```

Now I add them all to a list:

```
loadExecutionData();

final IBundleCoverage bundleCoverage = analyzeStructure();

reportsList.add(this);
```

at this point I want to call a method to generate the report, but it does not work. So far I am trying to use the examples provided on the jacoco website.

http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/examples/java/ReportGenerator.java

What I attempted to do was edit the `createReport` method, I create an `HTMLFormatter` and an `IReportVisitor`, loop through the report list and add the `visitInfo` and `visitBundle` then at the very end, call a `visitEnd()` which dumps the contents to a file. The problem is the problem is in setting `visitInfo` and `visitBundle` I overwrite the previous report.

I am hoping someone out there knows how to append reports to make one larger report for viewing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Luckily through reading and trial and error I found out how to programmatically create and merge jacoco code coverage reports.

The simple way is to create a list of bundle coverages, create a group and put it all together in a `MultiReportVisitor`

```
public void addToBundleCoverageList() throws IOException {

        loadExecutionData();

        bundleCoverage = analyzeStructure();

        coverageList.add(bundleCoverage);

    }

    public void createCoverageList() throws IOException 
    {

        for(int i=0; i<coverageList.size(); i++)
        {
            HTMLFormatter htmlFormatter = new HTMLFormatter();
            IReportVisitor visitor = htmlFormatter
                    .createVisitor(new FileMultiReportOutput(reportDirectory));


            visitor.visitInfo(execFileLoader.getSessionInfoStore().getInfos(),
                    execFileLoader.getExecutionDataStore().getContents());

            visitors.add(visitor);

        }

    }

    public void createReportFromList() throws IOException
    {
        MultiReportVisitor mrv = new MultiReportVisitor(visitors);
        IReportGroupVisitor irgv = mrv.visitGroup("group");
        for(int i=0; i<coverageList.size(); i++)
        {
            irgv.visitBundle(coverageList.get(i), indexHtml);
            System.out.println("Processing: " + coverageList.get(i).getName());
        }
        mrv.visitEnd();
    }
```